# There is a component overview?

Tags: maven, plugins, inversion-of-control

Is there a reference list of many, perhaps all, components that can be imported into a plugin with the help of IoC? (For example, is a goal to list archetypes)

I have found only a very small list: http://maven.apache.org/shared/index.html

**Edit:** more lists

http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Mojo+Developer+Cookbook